# how to align contents in div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am practicing hands-on project with `HTML` & `CSS` using flex, this project has seven rows and 4 columns, I have used `div` to create columns and so far I am working on the first column which mentions price but I am unable to do so as per the image I have attached of the project. I have shared my code below of HTML and CSS.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(24, 30, 30);
  margin-top: 1%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
}

#main-container div {
  background-color: bisque;
  align-items: center;
  width: 65%;
}

#main-container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #117CC0;
}

#main-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div>
    <h1>10.99</h1>
    <p>UDS/DAY</p>
    <button>SELECT</button>
    <P>Total 76.93 USD</P>
  </div>
  <div>car image</div>
  <div>capacity</div>
  <div>features</div>
</div>
```

If someone can please help me how to do it and also in making me understand the logic.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add display:flex; to every div in #main-container.

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(24, 30, 30);
  margin-top: 1%;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
}
#main-container > div > img {
    width: 100%;
}
#main-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 15%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 25%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 30%;
}
#main-container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    width: 30%;
}
#main-container div {
  background-color: bisque;
  align-items: center;
  width: 65%;
}

#main-container button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #117CC0;
}

#main-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p, h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-container">
        <div>
            <h1>10.99</h1>
            <p>UDS/DAY</p>
            <button>SELECT</button>
            <P>Total 76.93 USD</P>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="green-car2.png" />
            <p>Extra Small Car</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>x4 Passengers</p>
            <p>x4 Passengers</p>
            <p>x4 Passengers</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Air Conditioning</p>
            <p>Air Conditioning</p>
            <p>Air Conditioning</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Lukas as this really helped in understanding but I am trying to place icons next to the `passenger div` in your code above but somehow it is enlarging the width of the row, I tried playing with css but not able to do so

Comment: @user20086268 add icons inside <p>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want tables, so I recommend that you use appropriate [table tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
Below is an example of the implementation (using table tags and flex):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing on IE 11</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      button {
        background-color: #3b5998;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 3px 10px;
      }

      td {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      span,
      button {
        margin: 1px 0;
      }

      td > span:nth-child(1) {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      td > span:nth-child(2) {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #595959;
      }
      td > span:nth-child(4) {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #8c8c8c;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page-container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Example header 1</th>
          <th>Car image</th>
          <th>Capacity</th>
          <th>Features</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span>10.99</span>
            <span>USD/DAY</span>
            <button>SELECT</button>
            <span>TOTAL <b>76.93</b> USD</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to learn how to use flex, I recommend that you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Best regards, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you `Mateusz Szostek` for helping and for the suggestion